# Why doesn't sudo -E keep my $HOME environment variable?

Tags: rhel, sudo, environment-variables

On my Red Hat machine, when I run the command `echo $HOME` with my normal user account, I get `/home/snrub`. When I run the command `sudo vim foo.txt` and inside vim I type `echo $HOME` I get `/root` returned. I want it to return `/home/snrub` instead so that it will parse my cool Vim plugins, even when I'm editing a file with sudo. According to the sudo manpage, the `-E` or `-H` options should work, but if I run `sudo -E vim foo.txt` or `sudo -H vim foo.txt` or `sudo -EH vim foo.txt` they all still don't parse my home .vimrc file and return `/root` when I type `echo $HOME`.

I have also tried adding the following line to the sudoers file, and saving:

```
Defaults   env_keep += "HOME"
```

Still not working. If I run `sudo vim foo.txt` and then inside Vim type `echo $HOME` it still says `/root`. Similarly (and to verify that this is not strictly an issue with Vim), if I type `sudo emacs foo.txt` and press Enter, then type Alt-X, type `getenv` and press Enter, then type `HOME` and press Enter, it will still return `/root`. How do I make it return `/home/snrub`?

Comment: I assume you mean inside vim's command mode, you type `!echo $HOME`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Inside Vim I type `echo $HOME` and it returns /root.

Answer (score 0):

As a security precaution, `sudo` resets a list of environment variables (TERM, PATH, HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_*) under the `env_reset` option, which is enabled by default. In order for HOME to carry over from your user account to a `sudo` environment, you would have to either:

- use the SETENV tag on the sudo rule along with the `-E` option, or
- specifically unset the `env_reset` option.

Additionally ensure that `always_set_home` is off (which it is by default).

See the [sudoers man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man.html) for all the details and interactions.